# Unable to use the css-loader using an ES 6 module import statement

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, css-loader

**index.js:**

```
import foo from "./foo.js"; // works fine
import blah from "./blah.js"; // works fine

import css from "style-loader!css-loader!../content/site.css"; // fails with exception
```

I am using Webpack 4.20.x. When I use the ES6 module import statement to import and bundle a CSS file, I get an exception in the console (see below) and my CSS does not load on the page.

**Exception:**

> Failed to resolve module specifier 
>   "style-loader!css-loader!../content/site.css".  Relative references
>   must start with  either "/", "./", or "../".

I've got the loaders instsalled as dev dependencies.

Excerpt from package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
```

1. I know I can configure the loaders in my `webpack.config.json` but I want to, just for practice, configure them inline.
2. I know I could use the CommonJS style webpack-`require()` syntax also for the inline import in place of ES 6 module style `import`, but I want to the import first.

I am basically trying each and every syntax one by one.

EDIT

In response to the commenter @axm__, I was asking webpack to bundle my files. Here is what my `webpack.config.js` looked like at that time. I wasn't using configuration based loaders at the time.

```
const path = require("path");

// How to use source maps, css, sass
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, "scripts/index.js"),
        contact: path.resolve(__dirname, "scripts/contact.js"),
        about: path.resolve(__dirname, "scripts/about.js")
    }, 
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    /* module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.css/, 
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { 
                        loader: "css-loader", 
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    } */
};
```

Comment: Do you directly import `index.js` in the browser? Are you sure `webpack` first bundled the code and you imported the **bundled** code in the browser. I just tested it and it seems to work fine (webpack 4.20.2)

Comment: @axm__ Yes, I was asking webpack to bundle my file and was using the file from `dist/[name].js`. I have edited the question to include my `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: @axm__ Also, if I used the inline webpack `require()` module loader or the configuration based loader, then everything works fine. Only the inline ES 6 module loader didn't.

Comment: hmm interesting.  what happens if you directly import the module without assigning a variable to it? like: `import "style-loader!css-loader!../content/site.css";`

Comment: Will try that soon and post. Currently doing another thing.